# Do I need to watch Ant-Man and the Wasp and Captain Marvel before watching Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, suggested-order, captain-marvel, ant-man-and-the-wasp, avengers-endgame

I am going to watch *Avengers: Endgame* soon but I have not seen *Ant-Man and the Wasp* and *Captain Marvel* yet so I wanted to know if I can skip them and still have no issue to understand *Avengers: Endgame* or not?

Comment: Have you seen *Avengers: Infinity War*?  It matters.

Comment: You know, it wouldn't hurt. And see if you can fit in Doctor Strange too.

Comment: You need the midcredit scenes of both movies.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Captain Marvel is set before *Infinity War* and *Ant-man and the Wasp* is set at the same time, so it's really not *that* important to watch them. Although, I'd say you have to watch mid-credit scenes of these movies because they play as teasers for Endgame.

You may skip *Captain Marvel* though if you have background information about that character. However, you won't know the connection between Captain Marvel and Nick Fury, but it's not really important.

*Ant-Man and the Wasp* is also set before and during Infinity War. The only thing you need to know is the Quantum Realm which plays an important role. However, you can still get an idea about it while watching Endgame.

From [Express article](https://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/films/1118172/Avengers-Endgame-Captain-Marvel-end-credits-scene-Ant-Man-and-the-Wasp-post-credits-scenes),

> While both are set before Infinity War, they could contain something of a teaser for what the Avengers’ plan in Endgame will be in the fightback against Thanos.
>
> But ultimately, **if fans don’t have time to see either movie before Endgame it isn’t the end of the world.**
>
> However, both films’ mid-credits scenes are the only thing that audiences really should watch before the Marvel epic is out this weekend.

Comment: I’d say Ant-man and the Wasp sets up a lot of importance for Endgame but they cover it reasonably well in Endgame so yeah not truly necessary but if you have time certainly go for it.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I've yet to see Endgame, but isn't the end credits scene from Captain Marvel (no not the one with Goose) meant to be a scene from Endgame? Even if it's not I don't see how it's too hard to figure out how she turns up with the Avengers, assuming you remember the scene from Infinity War.

Comment: Isn't ant man and wasp set AT THE SAME TIME as infinity war? hence the sound of the snapping at the end of ant man and wasp.

Answer (score 12):

I would like to explain these two mid-credits scenes in addition to [AJ's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/99616/65795).

*Ant-Man and the Wasp*

> In a mid-credits scene, Pym, Lang (*Ant-man*), Hope, and Janet plan to harvest
>  quantum energy to help Ava remain stable. While Lang is in the quantum
>  realm doing this, the other three disintegrate. 
>  **Note:** You might not know these characters, but actually you just need to know is that Ant-man is been trapped in the quantum realm.

*Captain Marvel*

> In a mid-credits scene, set in the present day, the activated pager
>  is being monitored by the Avengers when Danvers appears.

That's all you need to know before watching *Avengers: Endgame* (not counting *Infinity War* of course).

Comment: Very helpful too

Answer (score 7):

All you really need to know about Captain Marvel is that she showed up in the 90s, met Fury, and had an adventure. She gave him the pager before leaving for deep space; told him not to use it unless it was an emergency. Oh, and she can shoot mucho powerful energy beams, and fly, and is super strong.

Ant Man?  Nothing important other than when we last saw him (in a post credits scene) he got trapped in The Quantum Realm when the people meant to pull him out got snapped out of existence. Theoretically he can't get out on his own, though from Endgame trailers it's obvious that he gets out