# What do I need to see before Spider-Man: Far From Home?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, suggested-order, spider-man-far-from-home

I have seen *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, but have not yet seen several other MCU movies (including *Civil War*, *Black Panther*, *Infinity War*, *Endgame* and many more).

However I gather from various Internet spoilers that:

> In *Infinity War* half of everybody dies, but in *Endgame* they come back.

How independent is *Spider-Man: Far From Home*? Do I need to have seen up to the end of *Endgame*, or is *Spider-Man: Homecoming* enough?

I'd still like to see the rest of the MCU at some point, so will *Spider-Man: Far From Home* give me more spoilers?

Comment: Spider-Man: Far From Home is the epilogue of the MCU Phase 3, so you could have the conclusion of lots of stuff in it. I've not seen it yet, but I know for sure there is major spoiler that you didn't mention about the end of Avengers: Endgame.

Comment: @TinyDoowy It certainly deals with said major spoiler and also wraps up a few things from Phase 3. However, most of what is wrapped up comes from IW/Endgame imo.

Comment: Thanks TheLethalCarrot and Ankit Sharma for both of your answers. My son and I have watched everything up to Ant Man, plus a few out of order ones. Sounds like the best option is for us to just keep going, rather than try to skip ahead just so we can catch Far From Home at the cinema. Maybe we'll catch up in time for the next one! :)

Comment: @SaxonDruce In addition to the things that have been mentioned here, the post-credits scene will not make sense if you haven't seen *Captain Marvel.*

Comment: Confirming @Mason Wheeler's point. I haven't seen Captain Marvel and the post-credits took a left turn. Had to ask friends to explain.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It concluded the Infinity Saga and starts where Avengers: Endgame left. From [comicbook.com](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2019/06/24/spider-man-far-from-home-infinity-saga-ending-marvel-kevin-feige/)

> "Those were the films that were culminating the entire Infinity Saga
>   of the MCU. And as we were working on Endgame we realized that the
>   true end of the entire Infinity Saga, the final film of Phase 3, had
>   to be Spider-Man: Far From Home, because

### spoiler

> we lose Tony Stark

at the end of Endgame.

> "The relationship between Peter Parker and Tony Stark is so special
>   over the five films that Tom Holland has portrayed Spider-Man in the
>   MCU, that we needed to see where his journey went, and see how does
>   Spider-Man step out of the shadow of his mentor, Tony Stark, and
>   become the true hero that he was always meant to be. And it's for that
>   reason that Endgame and Spider-Man: Far From Home are essentially two
>   pieces of the same story, and it's not over yet until Spider-Man: Far
>   From Home."

And of course, you need to see *Spider-Man: Homecoming* (which you already saw) where Tony and Peter escalate their relationship which started in *Captain America: Civil War*.

And to understand *Avengers: Endgame* you need to watch *Avengers: Infinity War* and for that, you need to watch a lot of films. For this, refer to this question:

[What films to watch before Avengers: Infinity War for better understanding?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83268/1190)

Also, you can refer:

[Do I need to watch Ant-Man and the Wasp and Captain Marvel before watching Avengers: Endgame?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99615/1190)

Answer (score 14):

Having just watched it I can say that you don't really need to have seen a lot of the MCU to understand what is going on in *Far From Home*. Of course you should watch *Homecoming* as you already have done as that sets up the characters for Spider-Man.

The film also deals with the fallout of *Endgame* as quite a major point. Therefore, to understand it you really need to watch *Endgame* and to understand *Endgame* you at least need to watch *Infinity War*.

You might also consider watching *Civil War* as that introduces the Peter/Tony relationship which is quite important for the events of *Far From Home*.

I also have [an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/208516/58193) over on SFF where I discuss what one should watch before watching *Endgame*. However, if you're not too much of a fan of the rest of the MCU and only really want to watch the *Spider-Man* side of things I'd suggest just those 4 films are the core to get to grips with the story of *Far From Home*.

---

*Far From Home* does make a few references to the early *Iron Man* films which are quite nice and so would enhance your viewing but they're not really necessary. The most important ones are shown in flashbacks and the little details are more to do with how Peter is like Tony which are more subtle nods and clues.

I'd say you might want to at least watch *Iron Man* here as *Far From Home* does deal with

> the death of Tony in Endgame

and understanding why that is so important at least starts in *Iron Man*. You'd also then pick up on more of the subtle nods I mentioned earlier.

Comment: But to understand  Infinity War. I need to watch GotG also and Thor and few more

Comment: @AnkitSharma Sure and I added that disclaimer but if you're only watching it for the Spider-Man storyline you don't really need to see the other films. You might not understand IW as well but that doesn't matter because you're not watching it for that.

Comment: That will make you scratch you head and pull beard hairs :p

Comment: @AnkitSharma Not really, you won't understand some of the character relationships but the overall theme of the film is really easy to understand and explained in the film itself.

Comment: "You might also consider watching *Civil War* as that introduces the Peter/Tony relationship which is quite important for the events of *Far From Home.*"  Actually, once they got the rights to go ahead and make *Spider-Man* MCU movies, the producers kind of retconned that.  Remember in the climax of *Iron Man 2*, when one of the Hammer droids goes to attack a little kid wearing an Iron Man mask, and then Iron Man shows up and saves him?  [That kid was Peter Parker.](https://io9.gizmodo.com/tom-holland-confirms-that-peter-parker-appeared-in-iron-1796423390)

Comment: @mason that’s the start of their interaction not really their relationship. I wouldn’t confuse the two.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Fair enough.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: “But to understand Infinity War. I need to watch GotG also and Thor and few more” — I think *Infinity War* is pretty watchable without seeing any *Guardians* or *Thor* movies. You will initially miss out on some of the depth and impact, not having seen the characters' histories, but plot-wise, it's pretty much all there in the movie. The depth can be the pleasant bonus you get after re-watching all 23 films at home!

Answer (score 3):

The other two answers are correct in some way, but I would suggest watching **all** MCU movies before *Spider-man: Far From Home*. MCU is an inseparable story of all superheroes, and trying to pull out a whole story of one them is not really good, because you still won't understand some parts.

If you really want to go to the cinema now, then I suggest watching at least one of *Iron Man* movies, *Captain America: Civil War*, *Spider-man: Homecoming*(that you have already watched), *Avengers: Infinity War*, and *Avengers: Endgame* if you can find it on the Internet(I personally have found a 720p version, and it's quite good). Watching these films will help you understand **part** of Spider-man story.

If you don't have to go to the cinema now, then you should watch all MCU movies in chronological order([here is the order](http://digg.com/2017/how-to-watch-all-of-marvel-cinematic-universe)), and wait for *Spider-man: Far From Home* go online.

Good luck in becoming a Marvel fan!

Comment: Indeed - watching any MCU movie without watching all the previous ones is like picking a Pink Floyd album you never heard before and starting from the middle of the album.

Comment: @Renan That's right =)

Comment: I really disagree with this answer. While there is an ongoing plot throughout most (arguably maybe even all) of these movies, most individual plot points are really not necessary to follow what's going on unless you're terrible at extrapolation.

Comment: @Cubic I concur! :-)

Comment: Chronological order? Like an *animal!?* [No sir!](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/208442/440)